# Error to Migrate DB Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, dbmigrate

Im trying to use this migration but i keep getting the error, like these

This is my Migration file

```
class CreateEmployees < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :employees do |t|
      t.string :name 
      t.date :hiredate 
      t.float :salary 
      t.boolean :fulltime , :default => true 
      t.integer :vacationdays 
      t.text :comments
    end 
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :employees
  end
end
```

when i try to execute rake db:migrate get this error:

> ==  CreateEmployees: migrating ================================================
>   -- create_table(:employees) rake aborted! An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
>
> SQLite3::SQLException: table "employees" already exists: CREATE TABLE
>   "employees" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "name"
>   varchar (255), "hiredate" date, "salary" float, "fulltime" boolean
>   DEFAULT 't', "vacationdays" integer, "comments" text)
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sql
>   ite3-1.3.8/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in`
>   new'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in
>   `prepare'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:134:in`
>   execute'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:328:in `block in execute'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:425:in`block in log'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in
>   `instrument'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:420:in`log'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:328:in `execute'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:190:in`
>   create_table'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:625:in
>   `block in method_missing'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:597:in`
>   block in say_with_time'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:597:in
>   `say_with_time'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:617:in`
>   method_missing'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:383:in
>   `method_missing' /Users/YuriAguirre/Documents/Aptana Studio 3
>   Workspace/company/db/migrate/20130923140626_create_employees.rb:3:in`
>   up'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:534:in
>   `up'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:574:in`
>   exec_migration'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:555:in
>   `block (2 levels) in migrate'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:554:in`
>   block in migrate'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:294:in
>   `with_connection'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:553:in`
>   migrate'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:709:in
>   `migrate'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:959:in`
>   block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1005:in
>   `block in ddl_transaction'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:202:in`
>   block in transactio n'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:210:in
>   `within_new_transact ion'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:202:in`
>   transaction'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:209:in `transaction'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1005:in`
>   ddl_transaction'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:958:in
>   `execute_migration_in_transaction'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:920:in`
>   block in migrate'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:916:in
>   `each'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:916:in`
>   migrate'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:764:in
>   `up'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:742:in`
>   migrate'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:42:in
>   `block (2 levels) in ' Tasks: TOP => db:migrate (See
>   full trace by running task with --trace)

Comment: You've received answer: `SQLite3::SQLException: table "employees" already exists` You've provided not enough details to judge why you have this table created, maybe you've made it by hand, maybe it was created by another migration, who knows.

Comment: Oh now i saw, im a newbie at Rails how can i recreate or drop that table that already exist?

Comment: The Good Way is to use migrations for all changes made to db, so you won't get lost later. I don't know if you want to create that table from scratch or modify it, it latter one you should use `add_column :table_name, :column_name, :column_type` syntax

Comment: Oh, got it, but i still don't know how i can drop that table now and create the table again haha cause i have no ideia if i have created the table with the right statement.

Comment: You've got answer in migration you provided ;) Just write `drop_table :employees` in `self.up` part (or `change` instead of both `self.up` and `self.down`) or remove it by hand from sqlite console.

Comment: Oh ok! did it and work! thx man!

Comment: Ok, so I will add this as an answer so can mark it as  answered and question will disappear from unanswered ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've written in comment, you are receiving that error because of:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: table "employees" already exists
```

Which simply means you already have that column in your database. You can resolve that in few ways:

- changing migration to modify instead of create:

  ```
  class CreateEmployees < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def self.up
      add_column :employees, :name, :string 
      (...)
      end 
    end

    def self.down
      remove_column :employees, :name
    end
  end
  ```
- add another migration which will drop whole table (obviously, that one should be with earlier timestamp than modifying one so table will be dropped first and then created again):

  ```
   class RemoveEmployees < ActiveRecord::Migration
     def change
       drop_table :employees
     end
   end
  ```
- drop table by hand from console, but that's not a very good option as you should learn to use migrations for altering your database, of course that w'd be the fastest one (if you know how to use console) and will make no harm if that's just some learning project, but still, you should learn good habits when you can.

You might also want to use newer syntax (AFAIK) `def change` instead of `self.up` and `self.down`, less letters to type and less duplication ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your employees tables is already created in your database. You need to fix it then you can do it in two ways 1. drop the database and create one more or 2. run the down migration then up migration

```
rake db:drop
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 1):

Your migration is not completely run.You should rollback migration and migrate again.

```
rails db:rollback
rails db:migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

You ran that migration already with an error in it. So the migration ran halfway, creating the table incompletely. Rollback that migration, and then run the migration again.